# How can I add rows to datatables with twig loops from arrays?

Tags: jquery, arrays, symfony, datatables, twig

This is my array `group`:

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => Fields {#7444 ▼
    -id: 1
    -name: "ID"
    -unique_id: "6ab8c870ed"
    -productgroup: PersistentCollection {#7448 ▶}
    -type: Type {#7525 ▼
      +__isInitialized__: true
      -id: 2
      -name: "hidden"
      -unique_id: "5e1086c862"
      -label: "hidden"
       …2
    }
  }
  1 => Fields {#7526 ▼
    -id: 2
    -name: "Name"
    -unique_id: "deb1e9ddda"
    -productgroup: PersistentCollection {#7527 ▶}
    -type: Type {#7529 ▶}
  }
  2 => Fields {#7530 ▶}
  3 => Fields {#7534 ▶}
]
```

And this my array `columns`:

```
array:3 [▼
  "id" => ReflectionProperty {#7240 ▶}
  "name" => ReflectionProperty {#7241 ▶}
  "type" => ReflectionProperty {#7244 ▶}
]
```

This is the way I am adding the rows to my datatable:

```
 $(document).on('change', '.item-select', function() {

    var optionValue = $(this).val();
    var myArray = [];

    {% for key, value in group %}
    if(optionValue == "{{ value.id }}"){
      var id = "{{ value.id }}";
      var name = "{{ value.name }}";
      var type = "{{ value.type.name }}";
    }
    {% endfor %}


    if (optionValue) {
      table.row.add({
        {% for key, value in columns %}
        {% if key == "id" %}
        "{{ key }}": id,
        {% elseif key == "name" %}
        "{{ key }}": name,
        {% elseif key == "type" %}
        "{{ key }}": type,
        {% else %}
        "{{ key }}": '',
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      }).draw();
      $('option', this).first().prop('selected', true);
    }

  });
```

It is working fine. The problem is, it is hardcoded. But my fields and content are always different. In this example it is `id:1, name: ID, type:hidden` but in other cases it could be `id:14, profession:teacher, color: blue, friends: 14`. So I need to replace the variables `id, name and type` But I just cannot figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give you example how you can do it dynamically through the javascript objects, in twig array you can assign your array to javascript object, or get it directly through ajax, it's up to you.

In order to create datatables with new columns, you need to destroy datatable and reinitialize it.
Documentation for destroying and loading new columns in table is here:

https://datatables.net/reference/api/destroy()

I created for you example in jsfiddle how to load dynamically data and columns you can adjust it for your needs:

```
var data = {
  "data": [
     {
      "id": "1",
      "One": "Row 1 - Field 1",
      "Two": "Row 1 - Field 2",
      "Three": "Row 1 - Field 3"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "One": "Row 2 - Field 1",
      "Two": "Row 2 - Field 2",
      "Three": "Row 2 - Field 3"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "One": "Row 2 - Field 1",
      "Two": "Row 2 - Field 2",
      "Three": "Row 2 - Field 3"
    }
  ],
  "options": [],
  "files": [],
  //in columns you need to map data to key in data array above!!
  "columns": [
    {
      "title": "id",
      "data": "id"
    },
    {
      "title": "One",
      "data": "id"
    },
    {

      "title": "Two",
      "data": "Two"
    },
    {
      "title": "Three",
      "data": "Three"
    }
  ]
}
```

And initialization:

```
 $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: "Bfrtip",
        data: data['data'] ,
        columns: data['columns']
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nicandr/xjue540a/4/

Here is basic example, how to do it.
Note you need to reinitialize table after you got data, because all data will be in object that you are going to provide to datatables.

Right now there is no option to load columns dynamically without reinitalizng, so only way is reinitialize it. Please check the link about destroy table, they are saying it there.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but this is actually too far away from what I need in this specific case.

Comment: You told that your fields content are always different, sometimes id, name, type and sometimes id, profession, color, friends, its new columns, and I provided they way to load columns. You just need create specific javascript object  that I provided above. If you just want to update data without changing columns you need to in my example load data like that: table.rows.add(data.data).draw() in my example

Comment: Yes, I think I have to merge the array `group` and `columns`. To solve my problem I think I only need to generate this array: `array:
  "id" => 1
  "name" => ID
  "type" => hidden
]`